# How to use Redis as a session storage for multiple aws instances or ELB?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, redis

I am beginner to use redis-server in my nodejs application I am using redis server as a session-store for my app as:

```
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(express);

var admin_session = express.session({
    key: 'admin_token',
    store: new RedisStore({
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 6379,
        db: 2
        // pass: 'RedisPASS'
    }),
    secret: 'aersda@#$32sfas2342'
});
```

This is working fine for single instance. But my query is for multiple instance serving from aws elb.

Actually I want redis server as a cluster which clear the session for all the instances if any changes is available inside any of the instance and cleared all the code level caching.

If its possible can anybody help me how to do this and whats the steps?

Thanks in advance,
Vijay

Comment: You need to run Redis in one place and connect to it from your various node servers. You could run Amazon's managed redis, which gives you a dns endpoint to use across the cluster.

Comment: is it not possible that there are redis servers on every instances of aws and all are in sync mode or cluster mode which cleared caching or session as per single instance' changes? If possible can you please give me idea for it or link where I see the steps.

Comment: Do you have more than one server? Or are you just running a node cluster in a single box?

Comment: yes I have 3 servers in load balancer.

Answer (score 4):

This is a fairly standard approach for sessions when you have multiple web servers behind a load balancer.

If you run a redis server on every web instance, then you need to enable sticky sessions on your load balancer.  This will work fine until you start auto-scaling: as soon as one of your web instances is removed from the pool, anyone with a session on that instance will lose it.

So you want to run a shared redis (or memcached) server for your caching and/or sessions.  With elasticache, you have the option of running a single node "cluster" and using the standard way of connecting, or running a true cluster and using the AWS library to connect to it.

For sessions, I would probably just use a single node and not bother with the elasticache client.

If you want to clear your caches when you do a deployment, you'll have to have a hook and write code to do this.  Or you could simply spin up a new Elasticache server, update your configurations, and destroy the old one.